# Steam halting execution of batch script

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt, steam

I'm trying to open a Steam game from a batch script and am running into a problem.

I've tried both these approaches:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

C:\asdf\Steam\steam.exe steam://rungameid/238960

echo ASDF
```

and

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

start "" "D:\fdsa\Path of Exile\PathOfExile_x64Steam.exe"

echo ASDF
```

Both of these open a command prompt, run Steam (if it's not running) and open Path of Exile successfully, but neither approach prints out ASDF into the opened command prompt (i.e. neither approach actually reaches the code I want to execute after opening the game). Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried: start "" "steam://rungameid/238960" ?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for steam and I also managed to fix it similarly for the next line which was running an autohotkey script. Still not sure why the second version of the script in OP didn't work, but I guess I'll leave it at this. Unfortunately, I can't accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: I'll make an actual answer. Mostly so if anyone else finds this question the answer will be easier to find then in a comment. Cheers!

Comment: If launching steam, opens up a new console window of its own, the parent batch file has no control of it and cannot interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above (just in case anyone else has this issue) this should fix it up:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

start "" "steam://rungameid/238960"

echo ASDF
```